# How to pass parameter in Form Scope for REST services in ColdFusion?

Tags: rest, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Today while working with ColdFusion 10 REST, I got an issues. I am not sure how to pass data to a REST service in FORM scope.
Here is my REST enabled CFC,

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restpath="/crudService" >

<cfset variable.myQuery = queryNew("Id,Name","Integer,Varchar",[[1,"Test1"],[2,"Test2"],[3,"Test3"]] )>

<cffunction name="getHandlerJSONForm" access="remote" httpmethod="GET" restpath="/formtest" returntype="query" produces="application/xml">
    <cfargument name="customerID" required="true" restargsource="Form"   type="numeric" >

        <cfquery dbtype="query" name="local.qryGetUserName">
            SELECT  Name
            FROM    variable.myQuery
            WHERE   Id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#customerID#">
        </cfquery>

        <cfreturn local.qryGetUserName>

</cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Here is the CFM code, calling the REST service,

```
<cfset restInitApplication("E:\Local Workspace\cfcs\rest","myfirstrest")>

<cfhttp url="http://cflocal.com/rest/myfirstrest/crudService/formtest" method="get" >
  <cfhttpparam  type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" >
  <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="customerID" value="1" >
</cfhttp>

<cfdump var="#cfhttp#">
```

In StatusCode I am getting `500 Exception obtaining parameters` ?

Please suggest whats going wrong here.

Comment: For starters, the "form scope" only contains values passed via a POST and your call and your method are both using GET. There's no such thing as a "form field" with a GET request, so dunno what one should expect from trying that with `<cfhttp>`.

Comment: And, TBH, if you're just starting out with REST, you're probably better off skipping ColdFusion's inbuilt stuff (which is generally regarded as being a bit rubbish), and just using taffy.io

Comment: @AdamCameron: Sorry Adam,My mistake . I was using `GET` . After modifying method to `POST` both in cfhttp and cfc, now everything seems to work properly. Thanks.